# Failed to add a new replica to SiriDB

Tags: database, time-series

## My Set-up

I've started two SiriDB server on the same node, but using different ports:

First server:

- server_name: %HOSTNAME:9010
- listen_client_port: 9000
- http_api_port: 9020

Second server:

- server_name: %HOSTNAME:9011
- listen_client_port: 9001
- http_api_port: 9021

---

## Situation

I've created a new replica using the following curl command:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9021/new-replica' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic c2E6c2lyaQ==' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{
    "dbname": "dbtest",
    "username": "iris",
    "password": "siri",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 9000,
    "pool": 0
}'
```

The response from the command above was `OK`.

But in the server logging I see the following error message:

```sh
Connecting to back-end server 'my-hostname-xxx:9010' failed (error: connection refused)
```

When performing a `list servers` query, it seems that the servers are not able to find each other:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9021/query/dbtest' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic aXJpczpzaXJp' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{"q": "list servers"}'
```

This is the response:

```sh
{"columns":["status"],"servers":[["offline"],["running | synchronizing"]]}
```

I can't find what's wrong, as the servers run on the same host. Therefore, they should be able to find each other right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your binding is incorrect. Can you check if this is the case?

By default SiriDB binds only to `127.0.0.1` (localhost) for security reasons.

Since `%HOSTNAME` is used, it might be so that SiriDB is listening on another interface.

If you are using a configuration file, you probably need to change both `bind_server_address` and `bind_client_address` to `::` (any).

Note: the same setting can be done using the environment variable `SIRIDB_BIND_SERVER_ADDRESS` and `SIRIDB_BIND_CLIENT_ADDRESS`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The binding was set to 127.0.0.1. After changing the binding to `::`, the servers were able to connect!